# Ionic-Angular.js Taking pictures and sending to server

Tags: angularjs, json, image, cordova, ionic-framework

So I have managed to use a custom directive to upload images to my server, through Angular.js. I have also managed to implement the camera functionality from Cordova.Now i want to sending images to the server

my controller :

```
$scope.getPhoto = function() {
            console.log("foncton of picture");
            navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 75, targetWidth: 320,
            targetHeight: 320, destinationType: 0 }); 
            //destination type was a base64 encoding
            function onSuccess(imageData) {

                console.log("success");

                //preview image on img tag
                $('#image-preview').attr('src', "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+imageData);
                console.log("success imageData");
                console.log(imageData);


                //setting scope.lastPhoto 
                $scope.lastPhoto = dataURItoBlob("data:image/jpeg;base64,"+imageData);
                //$localStorage.lastPhoto=dataURItoBlob("data:image/jpeg;base64,"+imageData);
                console.log("$localStorage.lastPhoto");
                console.log(imageData);
            }
            function onFail(message) {
                alert('Failed because: ' + message);
            }
        } 
        function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
        // convert base64/URLEncoded data component to raw binary data held in a string
         var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
         var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]

         var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
         var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
         for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++)
         {
            ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
         }

         var bb = new Blob([ab], { "type": mimeString });
         return bb;
        }   


var objInsc = new Object();
objInsc.imageJson=$scope.lastPhoto;

$http.post('http://@ip:8080/elodieService/evenements/',objInsc).success(function(response, status, headers, config){
             alert("SUCCESS ajout dans la table evenement!!");
});
```

i found null for imageJson

what can i do ,please help me :(

Comment: Why do you want to convert base64 to raw binary, base64 is better when communicating with server.

Comment: how to correct it ??

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented this feature in one of my project, and I will tell you how to do it, it needs a lot of effort to make it work.

**First: Convert an image uri to base64 to mime string**

This is the most tricky part of sending a picture to server.

```
var encodeImageUri = function(imageUri) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var c = document.createElement("canvas");
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            var img = new Image();

            img.onload = function() {

                c.width = this.width;
                c.height = this.height;
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                var dataURI = c.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
                var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(",")[1]);
                var mimeString = dataURI.split(",")[0].split(":")[1].split(";")[0];
                var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
                var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
                for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
                    ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
                }
                var bb = new Blob([ab], { "type": mimeString });

                deferred.resolve(bb);
            };
            img.src = imageUri;
            return deferred.promise;
        };
```

Second: Write the send method to send it to server:

```
var sendPhoto = function (sessionID, photoURI) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            if (photoURI == null || photoURI == "") {
                deferred.resolve(true);
            }

            encodeImageUri(photoURI).then(function(photoData) {
                var fd = new FormData();
                fd.append("PhotoData", photoData);
                $http.post("*****YOUR URL******", fd, {
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': undefined
                        }
                    })
                    .success(function(data, status, headers) {
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                    })
                    .error(function(data, status, headers) {

                        deferred.reject(data);
                    });
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        };
```

Explanation:
 1. you create a deferred object from **$q** service. 
2. you check for null reference of the photoUrl. 
3. you create a FormData, because Photos need to be send as formData. 
3. make the call to http post, and change the `content-type` of headers to **undefined**
4. handle the call back 
5. return the promise.

hope it will help you, if you need any help let me know. Happy Coding. ;)